# How do I autocomplete on submit with twitter typeahead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

When a hint is shown using twitter typeahead I would like that to replace the query when a user clicks submit.

Example the user types in mo, the hint shows montana and the user can click submit and montana is submitted.

This is the same functionality if a use presses the right arrow key.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Could you simulate what you are trying to do in a JSFiddle, or JSbin?

Comment: here is a JSFiddle "http://jsfiddle.net/UkB7u/"

Comment: "Example the user types in mo, the hint shows montana" - It doesn't suggest Montana in your fiddle. Also right arrow key does not select the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stored the last results from the typeahead and set the first value when submit is clicked.
Probably there's a better way to do this, but didn't find any resource about how to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/wLak8L20/1/

**Filter**

```
 filter: function (movies) {
            // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript array
            window.lastMovies = movies;            
            return $.map(movies.results, function (movie) {
                return {
                    value: movie.original_title
                };
            });
        }
```

**Submit callback:**

```
jQuery('#submit').click(function() {
    try {
        $('.typeahead').val(lastMovies.results[0].original_title);
    } catch(e) {
    }
});
```